# Characteristic method , boundry conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I have problem with solving following task:

Using characteristic method find solution $ u(x,y) $ of

$$
\begin{aligned} x^{2} u_{x}+y^{2} u_{y} &=(x+y) u \quad \text { for }(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{+} \times \mathbb{R}^{+} \\ u\left(x, \frac{x}{2}\right) &=1 \quad \text { for } x>0 \end{aligned}
$$

I found out that 
$$
y(s) = \frac{-1}{s} + C \\
x(s) = \frac{-1}{s} + C \\ 
z(s) = -2s + C$$

where $z(s)$ is function $u(x(s), y(s))$ 
How can i find boundary conditions? 
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You solved the differential equations incorrectly, as $-\frac1{s+C}\ne-\frac1s+C$, and you did not use different integration constants in (as of that point) unconnected integrations.

$ds=\frac{dx}{x^2}$ integrates to $s=-\frac{1}{x}+\frac1{x_0}$ so that
$$
x(s)=\frac{x_0}{1-x_0s}.
$$
Similarly,
$$
y(s)=\frac{y_0}{1-y_0s}.
$$
Using these solutions in
$$
(x+y)ds=dz
$$
gives
$$
-\ln|1-x_0s|-\ln|1-y_0s|=z-z_0
$$
Now insert $y_0=\frac{x_0}2$, $z_0=1$ and eliminate $s$.

---

Alternatively, find that $$\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{dy}{y^2}\implies y^{-1}-x^{-1}=c_1$$ and
$$
\frac{dy-dx}{y^2-x^2}=\frac{dz}{x+y}\implies\frac{d(y-x)}{y-x}=dz
\\~\\
\implies z-\ln|y-x|=c_2=\phi(c_1)
\\~\\
\implies u(x,y)=z=\ln|y-x|+\phi(\frac1y-\frac1x)
$$
and with the initial conditions
$$
1=z_0=\ln|\frac{x_0}2|+\phi(\frac1{x_0})\implies \phi(t)=1+\ln|2t|
$$